# Portainer Stack - docker compose issue with MacVLan network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer

I am starting to use portrainer.io to manage my docker images, instead of Synology DSM Docker GUI.

Background information:
I've used MacVLAN to create an own IP address for my Pihole Docker, overall everything regarding this piHole is running fine with this settings, made by DSM GUI.
[environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Um9a.png) [network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpOLS.png) [volumes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO2TV.png)[ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRinx.png)

Problem:
I now would like to use portrainer.io to manage my Docker installation. Including the Stack option which should be docker compose.

I am now struggeling to get my PiHole Image up with this Docker script:

```
services:
  pihole:
  container_name: pihole
 image: pihole/pihole:latest
    networks: docker
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "67:67/udp"
      - "80:80/tcp"
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
      WEBPASSWORD: 'password'
      ServerIP: "0.0.0.0"
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
     - '/pihole/pihole/:/etc/pihole/'
     - '/pihole/dnsmasq/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/'
    # Recommended but not required (DHCP needs NET_ADMIN)
    #   https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#note-on-capabilities
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Does anyone have an idea why I get "Unable to deploy stack" as error message?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the service to use a network called "docker", but the network is not defined in the compose file. Is this the complete docker-compose file?

If yes, then you are missing the networks section:

```
networks:
  docker:
    external: true
```

Comment: After inserting the networks: I will still get "Unable to deploy Stack" Messages :-(

Comment: do you even need the networks section to begin with, perhaps removing it is the best option?

Comment: From my point of view, it is required, otherwise the DNS can not be properly configured if it hasnt its own IP